# Having trouble with Keras One Hot Encoding Memory Error

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to build a word level lstm model using keras and for that I need to create one hot encoding for words to feed in the model. I have around 32360 words around 130,000 lines. Each time I attempt to run my model I run into a memory error.

I believe the issue is the size of the dataset. I have been researching this for a couple of days now and it seems the solution is to either: create a generator where I do the one hot encoding and then load my data in batches or to reduce the number of lines I attempt to feed into the model. I cannot quite figure out the generator piece.

The error I get is:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 143. GiB for an array with shape
> (1184643, 32360) and data type int32

Is the generator the correct way to go? Is there any way to solve this otherwise? My code is below:

```
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index)+1

seq = []
for item in corpus:
    seq_list = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([item])[0]
    for i in range(1, len(seq_list)):
        n_gram = seq_list[:i+1]
        seq.append(n_gram)
        
max_seq_size = max([len(s) for s in seq])
seq = np.array(pad_sequences(seq, maxlen=max_seq_size, padding='pre'))

input_sequences, labels = seq[:,:-1], seq[:,-1]
one_hot_labels = to_categorical(labels, num_classes=vocab_size, dtype='int32')

n_units = 256
embedding_size = 100

text_in = Input(shape = (None,))
x = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size)(text_in)
x = LSTM(n_units)(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
text_out = Dense(vocab_size, activation = 'softmax')(x)

model = Model(text_in, text_out)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

filepath="new_model_weights/weights-{epoch:02d}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, 
                             monitor='accuracy', 
                             verbose=1, 
                             save_best_only=False, 
                             save_weights_only=False, 
                             mode='auto',
                             save_freq='epoch')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

epochs = 50
batch_size = 10

history = model.fit(input_sequences, one_hot_labels, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=1)
```

Comment: did u try sparse_categorical_crossentropy with simple integer encoded lables?

Comment: Hi @savvysavage32 did you get the answer for it?